# Parfor-loop restarts after executing the first set of iterations

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm having a problem in a script that executes a parfor-loop, I hope you can help me with it.

I didn't have this problem before and I think I didn't change anything that could cause it.

The problem is that the parfor-loop restarts after starting the parallel group with 4 workers and executing the first 4 iterations. This happens once and then normally executes all the iterations as it should.

Here is my code, simplified in order to show this problem:

```
parfor loopVariable = 1 : 21
    fprintf('%s - Running iteration %i/%i \n', datestr(datetime), loopVariable, 21)
    *statements*
end
```

And this is the output I get, you will note that the first 4 iterations are repeated:

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...
connected to 4 workers.
04-May-2020 11:43:21 - Running iteration 1/21
04-May-2020 11:43:21 - Running iteration 2/21
04-May-2020 11:43:21 - Running iteration 4/21
04-May-2020 11:43:21 - Running iteration 7/21

Analyzing and transferring files to the workers ...done.

04-May-2020 15:01:12 - Running iteration 7/21
04-May-2020 15:01:12 - Running iteration 1/21
04-May-2020 15:01:12 - Running iteration 2/21
04-May-2020 15:01:12 - Running iteration 4/21
04-May-2020 15:24:29 - Running iteration 3/21
04-May-2020 16:21:16 - Running iteration 6/21
04-May-2020 16:12:52 - Running iteration 13/21
04-May-2020 16:20:32 - Running iteration 10/21
04-May-2020 18:34:27 - Running iteration 12/21
04-May-2020 18:39:20 - Running iteration 9/21
04-May-2020 20:33:04 - Running iteration 5/21
04-May-2020 20:50:08 - Running iteration 11/21
04-May-2020 21:07:43 - Running iteration 8/21
04-May-2020 22:42:34 - Running iteration 15/21
05-May-2020 01:09:18 - Running iteration 14/21
04-May-2020 23:05:16 - Running iteration 18/21
04-May-2020 23:53:35 - Running iteration 19/21
05-May-2020 01:50:12 - Running iteration 17/21
05-May-2020 04:40:23 - Running iteration 16/21
05-May-2020 01:52:47 - Running iteration 21/21
05-May-2020 03:34:10 - Running iteration 20/21
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm running the script remotely using:

```
nohup matlab -nodisplay -nosplash  -r scriptFile -logfile outputFile.txt < /dev/null &
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segment of code you show is correct. Are you sure it's not some other part of the code or some of the `*statements*`?

```
>> parfor loopVariable = 1 : 21
    fprintf('%s - Running iteration %i/%i \n', datestr(datetime), loopVariable, 21)
   end
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...
Connected to the parallel pool (number of workers: 4).
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 1/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 6/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 5/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 15/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 19/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 2/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 8/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 7/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 13/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 17/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 3/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 10/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 9/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 14/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 18/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 4/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 12/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 11/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 16/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 21/21 
05-May-2020 11:10:56 - Running iteration 20/21
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, you were right! I had included a calling to a local function in the parfor-loop that I had created in order to save a workplace variable. I removed the line calling this function and the problem was gone. I don't know why that happens though. Thanks again!